# Energy calculator (html5 & javascript, NO jQuery!)

Tags: javascript, html

I wan't to make an energy/caloric calculator, but can't get it to work:

```
     <form name="EnergieForm"> 
    Kies een activiteit <br />
    <br>
    <SELECT NAME="Activiteit" id="Activiteit">
    <OPTION value="11" id="Fietsen">Fietsen (11 kcal per minuut)</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="9" id="Joggen">Joggen (9 kcal per minuut)</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="10" id="Voetballen">Voetballen (10 kcal per minuut)</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="3" id="Tv-workout">Tv-workout zoals yoga of stretchen (3 kcal per minuut)</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="7" id="Paardrijden">Paardrijden (7 kcal per minuut)</OPTION>
    </SELECT><br />
    Hoeveel minuten heeft u deze activiteit gedaan?<br />
    <input type="text" name="Aantalminuten" size="20"><br />
    <input type="button" value="Bereken de calorieën" onClick="berekeningEnergie()"> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /><br />
    <br>
    Aantal verbrande calorieën: <input type="text" name="betekenis" size="20"><br />
 </form>
```

This is my form and here is my JS:

```
function berekeningEnergie() {

if (document.getElementById('Fietsen').value == "11") {
document.EnergieForm.betekenis.value = 11*document.EnergieForm.Aantalminuten.value;
}

else if (document.getElementById('Joggen').value == "9") {
document.EnergieForm.betekenis.value = 9*document.EnergieForm.Aantalminuten.value;
}

else if (document.getElementById('Voetballen').value == "10") {
document.EnergieForm.betekenis.value = 10*document.EnergieForm.Aantalminuten.value;
}

else if (document.getElementById('Tv-workout').value == "3") {
document.EnergieForm.betekenis.value = 3*document.EnergieForm.Aantalminuten.value;
}

else if (document.getElementById('Paardrijden').value == "7") {
document.EnergieForm.betekenis.value = 7*document.EnergieForm.Aantalminuten.value;
}
```

I know the JS isn't complete, but I can't get it to work.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your code:

1) Your `onclick` attribute has `GetInventory()` and your function is named `berekeningEnergie`.  I think you mean `onclick="berekeningEnergie()"`.

2)  You need to check to see which `option` is selected by looking at the `selectedIndex` property of your `select` tag to determine which item is selected, right now you are inspecting each option which doesn't make sense.

3) I would recommend adding an `id="EnergieForm"` to your form tag and using `getElementById` to select it.  The way you are referencing it is a bit archaic.  This is a bit of an best practice/idiomatic issue and not necessarily a functional issue.

Comment: Okay, fixed stupid error, now it works, but how to do your step 2 and what do you exactly mean with step 3?